# wrong type deduction of function signature

Tags: c++, c++14

I stumbled on a strange phenomenon while developping a templated API for accessing the windows registry.

I thought I was smart by 'capturing' the ascii and unicode versions of the windows API in
static constexpr 'variabeles' of 2 t_api structs ( t_api_A and t_api_W ).

Everything was compiling fine ,but running not so much (exceptions on calling the 'captured functions').
So I used a piece of code (from Scott Meyers' book "Effective Modern C++") to see the deducted types.
Apparently if I place those 'function captures' in structs it doesn't work ,however a simple auto = ...; inside a function does.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong ,but I can't see why my approach is faulty.

Here's the code (some code is commented out because they purposefully generate errors)

```
#include<Windows.h>

//==============================================================================
namespace wreg {
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using t_oshandle     = HKEY;

struct t_api
{
    static constexpr 
    auto open_key    = ::RegOpenKeyExA;
    // Tried all of these :
    //  RegOpenKeyExA; &RegOpenKeyExA; (::RegOpenKeyExA); (RegOpenKeyExA); (&RegOpenKeyExA);
    //

    static 
    constexpr auto close_key     = ::RegCloseKey;
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
} // namespace wreg
//==============================================================================

template < typename T >
struct type_deduced;  // see Scott Meyers' "Effective Modern C++"

#define TYPE_DEDUCED( nr , t ) type_deduced< t > dummy_ ## nr

int main ()
{
    //type_deduced< decltype(RegOpenKeyExA) > s1;
    //TYPE_DEDUCED( 1 , decltype(RegOpenKeyExA) );           // 'dummy_1' uses undefined struct 'type_deduced<LSTATUS (HKEY,LPCSTR,DWORD,REGSAM,PHKEY)>'
    //TYPE_DEDUCED( 1a , decltype(::RegOpenKeyExA) );        // 'dummy_1a' uses undefined struct 'type_deduced<LSTATUS (HKEY,LPCSTR,DWORD,REGSAM,PHKEY)>'
    //TYPE_DEDUCED( 3 , decltype(wreg::t_api::open_key) );   // 'dummy_3' uses undefined struct 'type_deduced<LSTATUS (__stdcall *const )(HKEY,LPCSTR,DWORD,REGSAM,PHKEY)>'

    auto     hk = wreg::t_oshandle{};

#define ORIGINAL_APPROACH 0
#ifdef ORIGINAL_APPROACH // faulty version
    auto     res = wreg::t_api::open_key( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ,"SOFTWARE" ,0 ,KEY_READ ,&hk );
    if (res == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        res = wreg::t_api::close_key( hk );
    }
#else  // working version
    auto     open_key    = ::RegOpenKeyExA;
    auto     res = open_key( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ,"SOFTWARE" ,0 ,KEY_READ ,&hk );
    if (res == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
    {
        auto     close_key   = ::RegCloseKey;
        res = close_key( hk );
    }
#endif

    return 0;
}

//==============================================================================
```

Comment: What's the question? Besides "it doesn't work"?

Comment: the question is what am I doing wrong is the first version ?

Comment: Are you saying the code you've posted doesn't compile? It does on VS2015. Or are you saying it fails to open the registry key?

Comment: @praetorian : it does compile ,but the constexpr 'variable' are all nullptr while the auto's in the second version are not.

Comment: Have you tried providing a definition for those static class members?

Comment: @dyp: yes I did do such a thing ,but then I couldn't get it to compile (can't remember exactly what I did).

Comment: *"but the constexpr 'variable' are all nullptr "* So if you add `if( ! wreg::t_api::open_key) { std::cerr << "error!\n"; }` to the `ORIGINAL_APPROACH` "branch", it will print `error!`? Or did you merely observe it through the debugger?

Comment: @dyp: I had an if () ... else ... construction with breakpoints in both of them. It breaked in the (open_key == nullptr) part.

Comment: @dyp Adding `cout << (void*)wreg::t_api::open_key << endl;` to the `ORIGINAL_APPROACH` part prints 0s on VS2015 and non-zero on MinGW. And how the heck do you add a definition? I tried `constexpr auto wreg::t_api::open_key;` in the global namespace but neither gcc nor VS like that. gcc complains of conflicting declaration, while MSVC insists I need to provide an initializer there too.

Comment: @Praetorian: you've done all things I've tried. Even tried decltype(auto) .

Comment: @Praetorian just `decltype(t_api::open_key) t_api::open_key;` but that hits *another* bug in MSVC. Works fine in clang. (gcc also doesn't accept it, but the error message suggests it's confused)

Comment: Summing up @engf-010: It seems you've hit a compiler bug and unveiled another compiler bug :)

Comment: @dyp: Hoera ! :-( . So my original code is legal and should work ?

Comment: @engf-010 Backing up a bit, why are you doing this anyway? Do you really need to support both the `W` and `A` APIs? Unless you're writing software that needs to also run on Win98, just forget the `A` half exists, use the `W` half only, thus avoiding your abstractions, and weird MSVC bugs.

Comment: @Praetorian gcc 6.0 accepts `decltype(t_api::open_key) t_api::open_key;` as well (not tip-of-trunk, my build is a month old)

Comment: @Praetorian : good question ! Going to think about that. In the meantime it was a nice exercise.

Comment: Replacing `constexpr auto` with `const decltype(::RegOpenKeyExA)*` and providing a matching definition with an initializer results in `open_key` being non-NULL on MSVC. /cc @dyp

Comment: @Praetorian : did that too ,but didn't like it ,typing the function twice.

Comment: Appears to be related to pointer to function types. In this [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d94157ad4496a72b), VS2015 chokes on the `bar1` definition, but is happy with `bar2`. If you comment out the indicated line, then `bar1` prints 0s. File a bug report - connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @Praetorian : will do. thank you for your efforts.

Comment: bug filed. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1378031/bug-in-deducing-constexpr-of-function-pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug is resolved in VS 2015 RTM.