# use of a static constexpr member function returning auto inside class

Tags: c++, auto, c++14, constexpr

I'm trying to workaround a bug in MSVC 2015 that I encountered (see this question : 
[wrong type deduction of function signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519363/wrong-type-deduction-of-function-signature)).

So I came up with this :

```
#include<Windows.h>

namespace wreg {

using t_oshandle     = HKEY;

struct t_api
{
    static constexpr 
    auto fnc_open_key ()     { return ::RegOpenKeyExA; }

    //this doesn't compile :
    static constexpr auto open_key   = fnc_open_key();

    //these don't compile either:
    //static constexpr decltype(fnc_open_key()) open_key     = fnc_open_key();
    //static constexpr decltype(::RegOpenKeyExA) open_key    = fnc_open_key();
};

//this does compiles and runs :
constexpr auto open_key  = t_api::fnc_open_key();

} // namespace wreg


//int main( int argc ,_TCHAR* argv[] );
{
    auto     hk = wreg::t_oshandle{};
    auto     res = wreg::t_api::open_key( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ,"SOFTWARE" ,0 ,KEY_READ ,&hk );
    //auto   res = wreg::open_key( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ,"SOFTWARE" ,0 ,KEY_READ ,&hk );

    if (res == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        res = ::RegCloseKey( hk );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but it doesn't compile because of

**error C3779: 'wreg::t_api::fnc_open_key': a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined**

I don't get that. 
It's clearly defined at the point I use it.
And besides that ,within a class **usually** names local to the class definition can be use before its definition/declaration.

Question : Why is MSVC right or should my code compile ?

Comment: static constexpr 
    auto fnc_open_key ()     { return ::RegOpenKeyExA; } <-- the function call syntax. Where the parenthesis? That cannot be then deduced to what you want.

Comment: it not a function call ,it return a function pointer

Comment: Then auto*, pointer?

Comment: I can't see anything in the standard text to explain why this program would be ill-formed.

Comment: @AlexanderVX: What???

Comment: nope ,it's about why inside the class it's an error and outside the class it's not (the code outside the class compiles and runs OK.

Comment: @lightness races in orbit: so this also a bug in MSVC2015 ?

Comment: `[C++14: 7.1.6.4/11]` is the most relevant passage I can find, but it (and the other rules for `auto`, `constexpr`, inline class member function definitions, etc) still gives no indication as to why the definition wouldn't count here. I'd wait for an `auto`/`constexpr` expert to pop along, though.

Comment: I haven't gotten into a detailed analysis of the code yet, but in a quick test gcc 5.1 agrees with VC++ about which of these should and shouldn't compile (which doesn't explain the problem, but does at least hint that it's probably a real problem rather than just a VC++ bug).

Comment: This is [CWG 1255](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1255) (cc @LightnessRacesinOrbit )

Comment: @dyp: just read it ,but my code doesn't rely on the completeness of the class or members that haven't been declared yet. Or does it ?

Comment: It is clear that something like `struct foo { constexpr static auto s() { return sizeof(foo); } int arr[s()]; };` cannot compile. However, it is unclear if something like your example can compile, given that the bodies of member functions must be compiled as if they were placed *after* the definition of the class. For functions with return type deduction, it is necessary to inspect the function body to deduce the return type. (Even though it can compile in theory, making the distinction between those two cases might be hard.)

Comment: @dyp: it looks to me more like [CWG 1626](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1626), though that only states that it's so, without explaining why (and only proposes to explain the behavior, not change it).

Comment: @dyp: "bodies of member functions must be compiled as if they were placed after the definition of the class" ,didn't know that. It would however be an explanation. Worthy of an answer and let others comment to it ?

Comment: One other point: the code: `wreg::t_api::open_key` is clearly just wrong, regardless of any of the preceding discussion. `open_key` is not declared or defined inside of `t_api` at all, only inside of `wreg`, so there's really no room for question about why this code doesn't compile (or that it shouldn't).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: So you're saying that constexpr definitions/declarations inside a class only supplies scope to it and 'moves' the definitions/declarations to the surrounding namespace ?

Comment: @engf-010: No, I'm just saying the use of `t_api::open_key` can't work simply because the definition of `t_api::open_key` never compiled in the first place.

Comment: @JerryCoffin To me, 1255 and 1626 look like duplicates (if we exclude the title of 1626). I agree the example in 1626 is closer to the OP here.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Now ,you've really confused me. You're talking about the use of wreg::t_api::openkey (do you mean the call to it in main ?). But I clearly defined open_key in wreg::t_api (where the error is).

Comment: Yes, I mean the call in main can't possibly compile, because the definition it depends on didn't compile.

Comment: Ah ,I see. That call is there for completeness. It's all about why the wreg::t_api::open_key definition is not a valid one. The line (in main) below it that is commented out demonstrates that the definition outside the class is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue. Bug is resolved in VS 2015 RTM.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use decltype on auto function deduction:

```
auto fnc_open_key () -> decltype(::RegOpenKeyExA) {
       return ::RegOpenKeyExA;
}
```